# Clean up nested data pipe calls for better DX?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, nested, pipe

While this works. From a DX perspective the nested (data)(data)(data)
calls is real ugly.

```
 function nestedData(data){
  return pipe(
    text(performance.now()),
    style(
      pipe(
        rotate("deg", 60, 0, -45),
      )(data)
    )(data)
  )(data)
 }
```

Poked around on the ramda.js library however nothing jumped out as a possible solution.

Note: text() and rotate() are curried functions that take "data" last.
For example:

`test(performance.now(), data)`

There could be many more functions calls after text() and rotate() however removed here for clarity.

Comment: The operator to impolicitly thread an argument through a function call stack is `chain = f => g => x => f(g(x)) (x)` or `ap` where the composition takes place in `f`s 2nd arg. `chain`/`ap` are part of the monad/applicative instance of the function type. However, abstracting from argument passing takes away information. In order to understand such a composition you must know how monad/applicative works in general and what that means for the function type in particular.

Comment: I've been thinking about what you said @Iven Marquardt about chain and I've not had any luck so far. The "data" is always a JS Map Object of key, value pairs. The fn's return for example map.set("text", performance.now()) => map("text", 1000). Which is leading me to believe I would need to pursue monads here or just leave as with as you say with the extra info. Any leads would be most appreciated.

Comment: I tried to describe the reader monad in a more canonical manner in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74117480/5536315

Comment:  time. Would the flip side be writer and in more general sense the IO monad?